# Google App Script Regex for Extraction and Ignoring certain items

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I need a little help with regex extraction. The body content of the email appears like this when retrieved in google sheet from gmail (has asterisk before and after name /phone / email which is hyperlinked)

---

Body Content after being retrived from Gmail

```
Email: *abc@gmail.com `<abc@gmail.com>`*
First Name: *John Doe*
Phone Number: *123456789*
```

---

My current Regex code retrieves the data like this

```
*abc@gmail.com `<abc@gmail.com>`*
*John Doe*
*123456789*
```

---

What changes should be made to the code so that it ignores the asterisk before and after for all these and the email is retrieved as abc@gmail.com ignoring the second part of the hyperlink format? Like

```
abc@gmail.com
John Doe
123456789
```

```
    My Code is
    
    function extractDetails(message){
      
      var emailData = {
        date: "Null",
        fullName: "Null",
        emailAddr: "Null",
        phoneNum: "Null",
      }
      var emailKeywords = {
        fullName: "First Name:",
        emailAddr: "Email:",
        phoneNum: "Phone Number:",
      }
      
      
      emailData.date = message.getDate();
      emailData.body = message.getPlainBody();
      
      var regExp;
      
      regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.fullName + ").*");
      emailData.fullName = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      
      regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.phoneNum + ").*");
      emailData.phoneNum = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
      
      regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.emailAddr + ").*");
      emailData.emailAddr = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the last 6 lines of your code with:

```
regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.fullName + "\\s*\\*).*?(?=\\*)");
emailData.fullName = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString();
      
      
regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.phoneNum + "\\s*\\*).*?(?=\\*)");
emailData.phoneNum = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString();
      
regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.emailAddr + "\\s*\\*).*?(?=\\s)");
emailData.emailAddr = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString();
```

`(?<=Email:\s*\*).*?(?=\s)`

- `(?<=Email:\s*\*)` go to the point where it preceded by `Email:` followed by zero or more whitespace character `\s*`, followed by a literal `*`.
- `.*?` then match any character except for new lines as few times as possible. Until a whitespace character appears `(?=\s)`, See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BiB5I9/1).

`(?<=First Name:\s*\*).*?(?=\*)`

- `(?<=First Name:\s*\*)` go to the point where it preceded by `First Name:` followed by zero or more whitespace character `\s*`, followed by a literal `*`
- `.*?` then match any character except for new lines as few times as possible. Until a literal `*` character appears `(?=\*)`, See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWkfAN/1).

Comment: for all 6 line of codes, it is showing the following error if executed

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=First Name:s**).*?(?=*)/: Nothing to repeat`

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=Phone Number:s**).*?(?=*)/: Nothing to repeat`

`SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=Email:s**).*?(?=s)/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: @SamyAbdullah I updated the answer please check it again, the problem was that `\*` and `\s` were not correctly escaped.